# Instantiate a List inside of type initializer

Tags: c#, typeinitializer

Say I have a `struct` like so

```
public struct MyStruct
{
     string StructConfig { get; set; }
     List<string> Details { get; set; }

     public MyStruct
     {
         Details = new List<string>();
     }
}
```

And I instantiate this `struct` using:

```
MyStruct s = new MyStruct() 
{
    StructConfig = "Some config details"
}
```

I'm wondering how I could add a `foreach` loop that will add the details into the `Details` property, rather than doing:

```
MyStruct s = new MyStruct() 
{
    StructConfig = "Some config details"
}
s.Details = new List<string>();
foreach (var detail in someArray)
    s.Details.Add(detail);
```

Is this even possible?  Am I dreaming of code-luxury?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
MyStruct s = new MyStruct() 
{
    StructConfig = "Some config details",
    Details = new List<string>(someArray)
}
```

This works because `List<T>` supports initialization from `IEnumerable<T>` through [this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0.aspx).

If you need to do additional preparations on the elements of `someArray`, you could use LINQ and add a `Select`. The example below adds single quotes around each element:

```
Details = new List<string>(someArray.Select(s => string.Format("'{0}'", s)))
```

Comment: I think you need to remove the `;` as that will give an excpetion.

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
s.Details = new List<string>(someArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't want to initialize the list from an array but really want to be able to write the list elements directly in your initializer you can use a [collection initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

```
var myStruct = new MyStruct() {
  StructConfig = "Some config details",
  Details = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" }
};
```

<sup>Now, having a struct containing a string and a list of strings looks slightly weird but that doesn't affect how to answer the question.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

can do something like this

```
MyStruct s = new MyStruct
{
    StructConfig = "Some config details",
    Details = someArray.ToList()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call the extension method ToList() on the "someArray" collection, which will create a copy of it that you could assign to your struct property, like so:

```
MyStruct s = new MyStruct() 
{
    StructConfig = "Some config details",
    Details = someArray.ToList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
s.Details = someArray.Select(detail=> detail.ToString()).ToList()
```

Would prevent an exception being thrown were your array not a string[]. Of course, you may wish for the exception to be thrown in this case.

Also, it's worth considering why you are using a struct with a property that is a List; it may be better to have a class instead of a struct.